# Passing parameter to object data provider in wpf

Tags: wpf

I am passing int value to my dataprovider class but I am getting below error , could not able to make out what is the problem.

error says : Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Column  Source
Error       The text ' ' is not allowed after the closing '}' of a MarkupExtension expression. Line 13 Position 33. ObjectDataProvider  D:\Learing\WpfApplication1\ObjectDataProvider\MainWindow.xaml   13  33  Build

code is like below.
**window.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ObjectDataProviderExer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:ObjectDataProviderExer"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Provider" ObjectType="{x:Type src:Student}"
                MethodName="GetStudents">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <sys:Int32>20</sys:Int32>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Provider}}"></DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Student.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace ObjectDataProviderExer
{
    public class Student
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Student> _studentsList;

        private int _age;

        public int Age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set { _age = value; }
        }

        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        public Student()
        {
            _studentsList = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Student> GetStudents(int age)
        {
            CreateStudentCollection();
            return (ObservableCollection<Student>)_studentsList.Where(x => x.Age == age);
        }

        private void CreateStudentCollection()
        {
            _studentsList.Add(new Student() { _age = 10, _name = "Arun" });
            _studentsList.Add(new Student() { _age = 20, _name = "Avinash" });
            _studentsList.Add(new Student() { _age = 14, _name = "Avith" });
            _studentsList.Add(new Student() { _age = 20, _name = "Baskar" });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not reproducible. Are you sure that you have posted the correct XAML markup?

Anyway, your `GetStudents` method throws an exception because you are trying to cast an `IEnumerble<Student>` to an `ObservableCollection<Student>`. This won't work but you could create a new `ObservableCollection<Student>` and return this one:

```
public ObservableCollection<Student> GetStudents(int age)
{
    CreateStudentCollection();
    return new ObservableCollection<Student>(_studentsList.Where(x => x.Age == age));
}
```

If you copy the XAML markup you have posted into a new window and run the code with the above modifiction it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out about the xaml error and is due to other window which I had loaded in my solution .

Comment: typecasting was problem too and I changed it to as you suggested and it started working.